# eMachines monitor shows faded moving lines

Tags: windows-7, display, emachines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does my monitor show faded black lines moving everywhere?](https://superuser.com/questions/421988/why-does-my-monitor-show-faded-black-lines-moving-everywhere)

I recently got this monitor from one of my friends because my other monitor broke. I have an eMachines E15T4.

The problem is that there are faded lines moving on my screen. They go from down to diagonal and repeat that over and over.

If I change the refresh rate, it helps it so it's barely viewable, but then after a couple minutes it just comes right back. I get this issue in safe mode as well, and am fairly sure it doesn't have this problem in the BIOS.

Specifications:

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/421988/why-does-my-monitor-show-faded-black-lines-moving-everywhere  Trying to bo constructive here, you already asked and got a correct , accurate , answer. Did you check for ground loop issues, and interferance?  What has changed via your other question?  Why did you give up there, without using the Edit feature or commenting on the advice provided already?